# How does authentification with JWT work in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, rest, jwt

How does **authentication** with JWT in Spring Boot work? Do I return my custom user and I set a filed called token to the JWT or do I return a JWT with all user information within in it to be extracted  later? With the **JWT** for authorization I need my custom  user information returned to be displayed in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is few point JWT is designed to work:

1. Clients logs in by sending their credentials to the identity provider
2. The identity provider verifies the credentials; if all is OK, it retrieves the user data, generates a JWT containing user details and permissions that will be used to access the services, and it also sets the expiration on the JWT (which might be unlimited).
3. Client stores the JWT for a limited or unlimited amount of time, depending on the expiration set by the identity provider.
4. Client sends the stored JWT in an Authorization header for every request to the service provider.
5. For each request, the service provider takes the JWT from the Authorization header and decrypts it, if needed, validates the signature, and if everything is OK, extracts the user data and permissions. Based on this data solely, and again without looking up further details in the database or contacting the identity provider, it can accept or deny the client request. The only requirement is that the identity and service providers have an agreement on encryption so that service can verify the signature or even decrypt which identity was encrypted

[image]

A good hands-on example is [here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X80nJ5T7YpE)

Comment: yea i understood the basic , but as for my user entity it has more information to it than the usual user details (more than just username and password ) so i made a custom user details class that implements user details ,  took the user entity from constructor and got user name and password and authorities from that user entity , what i meant is i want to access that user entity information like (id / gender / pic url  ect .. ) can i extract that information from the JWT ?

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation.